# Spring: queryForList() of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate cannot select Json field in UTF-8

Tags: mysql, json, spring, utf-8

I have a problem about **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate** when use `queryForList()` method to select a **Json** field.

In my Database i hava a Json field name "**Type**" with value: `{"Demo.Name": "株式"}` and when i set debug on the list i retrieve, it become this: `"Demo.Name": "æ ªå¼"`

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, params);
```

I have already set utf8_general_ci for Database and set UTF-8 for each Table and if i write MySQL query on SQLyog it can show result exactly:

```
SELECT A.Type , JSON_EXTRACT(A.Type, '$."Demo.Name"') 
FROM Customer A 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(A.Type, '$."Demo.Name"') = '株式';
```

Note: i have tried to add `"useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;"` to connection url but it did't work.

Note2: other fields (not Json field) in Japanese value is Ok

Did i forget something ? Thanks for seeing my post and i very appreciate if you can give me some advice

Comment: can you please share your answer if you resolved by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

`æ ªå¼` is Mojibake for `株式`

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Mojibake**, check the following.
This discussion also applies to **Double Encoding**, which is not necessarily visible.

- The bytes to be stored need to be utf8-encoded.
- The connection when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing` text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4.  (I think your attempt at such needed `&` instead of `;`.)
- The column needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).
- HTML should start with `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.